# How to give values to arrays in c

Tags: c

I am getting error in the following program. I am unable to figure out why I am not able to store values in the array

```
main()
{
    int A[10];
    A = {3,1,2,3,4,1,5,8,9,0};
    printArr(A,10);
    printf("\n");

    BubbleSort(A,10);

    printArr(A,10);
    printf("\n----------------Bubble Sort Efficiently ---------------------\n");
    printf("\n");

    A = {3,1,2,3,4,1,5,8,9,0};

    BubbleSortEfficient(A,10);
    printArr(A,10);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the error I got:

```
73: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
80: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
```

Please clarify with reason why I am not able to store array elements.

Comment: `A={3,1,2,3,4,1,5,8,9,0};` You cannot assign array like this.

Comment: What the error says? And at what line?

Comment: 73: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
BubbleSort.c:80: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137671/declaring-and-initializing-arrays-in-c

Comment: I find this question useful for me so a +1 :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ANSI C does not have a syntax for defining *array aggregates* outside of array initializers. If you combine initialization with the assignment (which technically is not an assignment, but part of initialization) your code will compile:

```
int A[10] = {3,1,2,3,4,1,5,8,9,0};
```

Since you cannot reassign arrays, the portion of your program before the second call of `BubbleSortEfficient` should look like this:

```
int B[10] = {3,1,2,3,4,1,5,8,9,0};
BubbleSortEfficient(B, 10);
printArr(B, 10);
```

**EDIT :** (in response to comment by Keith Thompson) C99 introduces array aggregate expressions, but they cannot be assigned to arrays, because the standard does not have array assignments.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great Fact to note.

Comment: C does have array aggregates ("compound literals") starting with C99: `int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` is a valid expression. But this doesn't do the OP much good, since C doesn't have array assignment.

Comment: @KeithThompson Indeed, thanks for a great note! I edited the answer to include your point. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Curly braces are used for initialization, not assignment.  You should be able to do this:

```
int A[10]={3,1,2,3,4,1,5,8,9,0};
```

Comment: Is there any other way to aggregate arrays  again.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot assign directly to an array, because an array is not a modifiable lvalue. However, if you enclose an array with a structure, then you can assign to a structure.

```
struct array {
    int a[10];
};

const struct array x = { {3,1,2,3,4,1,5,8,9,0} };
struct array A;
A = x;
BubbleSort(A.a,10);
A = x;
BubbleSortEfficient(A.a,10);
```

Or, you can use the more traditional `memcpy()`:

```
int A[10];
memcpy(A, (int[]){3,1,2,3,4,1,5,8,9,0}, sizeof(A));
```

Comment: `int[]{3,1,2,3,4,1,5,8,9,0}` equals `(int[]){3,1,2,3,4,1,5,8,9,0}`? `int[]` means convert the `{3,1,2..}`(array literal) to type `int[]`?

Comment: @Sayakiss: Thanks, I corrected the answer, it should be `(int[]){...}`. Yes, that's a compound literal expression.

Comment: I Liked the memcpy stuff !! Vote up for it

Answer (score 0):

yes you can not assign values to the array like this. You have to assign it as follows,

'int A[10]={3,1,2,3,4,1,5,8,9,0};'