# How to initialize an array in C with one line?

Tags: c, arrays

This is my code

```
int numLeft[5];
void init() 
{
     numLeft = {5,4,3,3,2};
}
```

When I tried compiling this code, I got this error: "error: expected expression before '{' token.
I know in java something like this could work

```
int[] numLeft;
void init() {
       numLeft = {5,4,3,3,2};
}
```

Is there something i am missing in my C code? A quick google search isn't helping.

Comment: [duplicated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137671/declaring-and-initializing-arrays-in-c) Use `memcpy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int numleft[5] = {5,4,3,3,2}
```

is the way to go. Here `numleft` is the variable that is referring to the array, but to access each, you've to refer to it as `numleft[0]`, `numleft[1]`, likewise.

Comment: I need to declare numLeft as a global variable and initialize it in the function though

Answer (score 1):

`int numLeft[5] = {5,4,3,3,2};` wiil do the job

---

if you need to initialize the global array *each* time, need to use `memcpy()`, as suggested in the other [duplicate answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3137701/2173917).

Comment: I need the numLeft as a global variable though and initialize it each time in the function