# Multiple ways to initialize arrays in c programming

Tags: c, arrays

In how many ways we can declare an array in C programming? if there are many ways to declare an array in C, what are the best practices  or best way among?

So far I have been initializing an array like this:

```
int myArray[SIZE] = {1,2,3,4....};
```

What are the other ways do the same?

Comment: Check this link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm. BTW, it's the first google search result when searching for "C arrays"

Comment: You should trust what it says there :)

Comment: I know that link. That's not what am looking for. I need to  know how many ways are there to declare an array in C ?

Comment: There is only one way to *declare* an array. The are a couple of ways of *initializing* it though. One way you show, the other is setting each element one by one. Or a loop or `memset` if you want to set all elements to the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From C99, you can also use explicit indexes, called *designators*, in the initializer expression, which is sometimes very nice:

```
const int threetoone[] = { [2] = 1, [1] = 2, [0] = 3 };
```

The above is the same as

```
const int threetwoone[] = { 3, 2, 1 };
```

Answer (score 0):

> datatype arrayName[arraySize];

```
int x[10];
int x[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
```

you can look at this question for more details on ways to initialize an array in C
[declaring-and-initializing-arrays-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137671/declaring-and-initializing-arrays-in-c)